# AWS JS SDK (s3) ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: amazon-s3

Im a bit confused with the AWS SDK for JS in reference to its S3 utilization. The below is my code:

```
  AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: $rootScope.s3.akey, 
    secretAccessKey: $rootScope.s3.skey
  });
  s3=new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
  s3.listObjects({Bucket:$rootScope.s3.bucket}, function(err,data){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);
  })
```

This yields the error **net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**. The endpoint it is going to is similar to **https://bucketName.undefined.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/**

Obviously this wont resolve because of **undefined** being in the URL; however this doesn't even look like an s3 endpoint! It should follow a format like **https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketName/someFile.txt**

Has anyone else been encountering issues similar to this or is there something elementary that I am doing wrong.

**STR:**

1. Download SDK for S3 from AWS
2. Use code posted above (its in angular, but pretty self explanatory)
3. View errors in console.

Any help please?

Comment: How about setting a region?

Comment: Tried that as well...no dice, no difference to the error URI: **https://bucketName.undefined.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/**

Comment: _ however this doesn't even look like an s3 endpoint_ yes it does, obviously you have the undefined part but https://bucketName.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ is a valid endpoint (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html)  try to remove your angular code (`$rootScope.s3.bucket`)  and hardcode the bucket name to make sure it works, then its probably something in your directive

Comment: Thanks for the response! If s3 was in place of "undefined" I would agree with you. I would have assumed the constructor for the AWS SDK would take care of this. I DID make an interesting observation. When I use the SDK builder via AWS, I get the error listed above; however If I use the CDN - https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.6.3.min.js I receive a CORS issue (expected) and it points to the s3 endpoint https://s3.amazonaws.com/ 

Maybe this is a warning then to other users...the package builder from AWS did not return expected results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've debugged this a bit in the browser and found that it appears to be an issue with endpointPrefix being undefined.  This effects selecting the url template to use as well hence the strange url.

If we look in the debug version of the aws js sdk code there's an area where

```
regionConfig.rules
```

is used to find a match from derivedKeys (which is based on your service/region).  In mine I get:

```
"eu-west-1/*", "eu-*/*", "*/*"
```

The asterisks after the / indicate an undefined endpoint prefix. However the rule that we want matched in regionConfig.rules is:

```
eu-west-1/s3: "s3dash"
```

s3dash equates to the following template:

```
"{service}-{region}.amazonaws.com"
```

Which would work if service was s3 as you'd get:

```
s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

However because this rule is not found instead */* matches to:

```
"{service}.{region}.amazonaws.com"
```

Because service endpointPrefix is undefined (which is why we ended on this rule in the first place) you get 'undefined.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'

If the CDN works are we suggesting there's a bug in the custom download?

Comment: ON THE MONEY. I didnt do any other change besides using the CDN. In fact, I copy and pasted exactly what was in the resolved link to a local file, and still success.

Thank you for this detailed response!